# Связывание моделей в rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Всем привет! Изучаю ORM и столкнулся со следующей проблемой: у меня есть модель User и модель Book, модель Book имеет поле *author_id*, которое должно связываться с User.id. Не смог найти, как связать две модели так, чтобы *указанное поле ссылалось на определенное поле из таблицы*. Я попробовал прописать: `t.references :author, null: false, foreign_key: { to_table: :users, column: :id }` в миграции, которая создает Book, но после запуска миграции `rails db:migrate` в файле *schema.rb* все равно появляется следующее выражение: **`add_foreign_key "books", "users", column: "author_id"`**. То есть, если я правильно понял, мы устанавливаем следующую связь: Books.author_id -> Users.author_id, но не требуемый Users.id. Как это исправить?

Comment: Всё верно у вас получилось. Посмотрите в schema.rb - у books есть author_id, у users - только id. Попробуйте в консоли создать книгу и привязать автора, всё должно работать